# How do I bypass the "Flash Camera and Microphone Access" pop-up when using Pepper/PPAPI Flash in Chrome (via Selenium)?

Tags: google-chrome, flash, selenium

Chrome supports two flavors of Flash:  NPAPI and PPAPI (Pepper).  These two implementations seem to handle camera and microphone permissions differently.  Specifically, PPAPI (Pepper) does not appear to honor any previous grants of permission.

With NPAPI, which is the default, the first time I navigate to a Flash site that requests permission to use the computer's camera and microphone, an Adobe Flash pop-up asks the user to allow or deny access.  I allow access, and this grant is remembered.  The next time I navigate to that site, permission is granted automatically, without the pop-up.

When I want to test with PPAPI (Pepper) Flash, I specify the "--enable-bundled-ppapi-flash" and "--disable-npapi" command-line arguments to Chrome.  In this mode, the previous grants are ignored, and the pop-up is displayed every time.  I have not figured out how to detect this in Selenium and click on "Allow".

Does anyone know how to bypass this pop-up, either by clicking on "Allow", or by disabling it altogether?

Thanks.

**Update:**  I have discovered that non-Pepper Flash stores camera/microphone permissions in a file called 'settings.sol', stored in a directory specific to the site requesting access.  For example, on Windows, when the host at 1.2.3.4 requests access, the following file is created:

C:\Users[user]\AppData\Roaming\Macromedia\Flash Player\macromedia.com\support\flashplayer\sys#1.2.3.4\settings.sol

Note the space in "Flash Player".  This file is a local shared object, encoded as AMF.  I use the Python pyamf package to create a file that grants permanent access to a site:

```
from pyamf import sol

permissions = sol.SOL ('1.2.3.4/settings')
permissions[u'always'] = True
permissions[u'allow'] = True
permissions[u'klimit'] = 100
sol.save (permissions, 'my-settings.sol')
```

When I copy this to the appropriate directory, access is granted automatically.  But again, this does not work for Pepper Flash.

Pepper Flash ignores this directory, and instead gets a new temporary directory for each instance of Chrome:

C:\Users[user]\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir5976_6686\Default\Pepper Data\Shockwave Flash\WritableRoot#SharedObje
cts\6DMDJWLP\macromedia.com\support\flashplayer\sys#1.2.3.4\settings.sol

Unfortunately, the directory changes on each invocation.  If I could somehow discover the name of this directory, then I could upload the file before requesting access.

But I don't know how to discover the name of this directory.

Comment: I have the same issue. I'm searching for a solution now.

Comment: I think the Adobe engineer on this discussion page knows the answer, but this topic locked, and the new topic I opened on it has been ignored:

https://forums.adobe.com/message/7317768

Maybe you can understand what he's talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that my problem was specific to Selenium, and how I was using Selenium.

First, back to NPAPI Flash, which stores its permissions on Windows in a subdirectory under the user directory; for example:

```
C:\Users[user]\AppData\Roaming\Macromedia\Flash  Player\macromedia.com\support\flashplayer\sys
```

Pepper Flash does not use this directory for its permissions, and thus does not honor the settings stored there.  Instead, it stores its permissions files in a subdirectory that is underneath the Chrome user's data directory.

When I was creating a Chrome browser instance via Selenium, a temporary user data directory was created for the session  For example:

```
C:\Users[user]\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir5976_6686
```

Pepper Flash was storing its permissions files underneath this directory, but when the browser session ended, this temporary directory was deleted, and the settings were forgotten.

The solution is simple:  when starting Chrome via Selenium, specify the Chrome user's data directory via a command-line argument:

```
"user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\[user]\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data"
```

Pepper Flash will then store its permissions in this directory, and because it is a permanent directory that does not get deleted when the browser session ends, it will be there for the next instance, and thus the permissions granted will be remembered.

Answer (score 1):

On linux, the directory seems to depend on the application. chromium-browser seems to store them in

```
~/.config/chromium/Default/Pepper Data
```

Qt WebEngine programs seem to store them in

```
~/.local/share/[NAMEOFTHEAPPLICATION]/QtWebEngine/Default/Pepper Data
```

I needed to delete the directory to retract a permanent permission to access the webcam (which I had given to a site for testing).